# Copy/duplicate entire rows based on number in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want to be able to copy/duplicate several columns of data based on their qty in another column.
I have my data in col. A- C & the qty in D. Basically it is "A-C" times D.

And on the right, that is how I imagine the result to be.

[image]

Here's a sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8L445SfSEIrrPgwPaPryC72DK_zwvyCbU6ot1ezsYM/edit#gid=707375238

Comment: Inserting redundant copies of data rows may not be the best strategy to manage orders that specify multiple copies of an item. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Hi @doubleunary this is not for record keeping, this is to create barcode labels. So each individual package (book) would have a label. In cases there is more than 1 nos, then I want to be able to create more labels without having to manually duplicate the rows. And btw, I know excel/sheets has some way of creating barcodes, but we use a third party for this.

And thank you for your solution, I haven't checked it. But I didn't want you thinking this was an XY so I replied to this first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `query(flatten())` and `vlookup()` like this:

`=arrayformula( query( flatten( if( sequence(1, max(D2:D)) <= D2:D, A2:A, iferror(1/0) ) ), "where Col1 is not null", 0 ) )`

`=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(K2:K, A2:D, column(B2:D), false) ) )`

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W8L445SfSEIrrPgwPaPryC72DK_zwvyCbU6ot1ezsYM/edit#gid=707375238).